# reading individual bytes of multiple binary files using the Python module fileinput

Tags: python, file-io, python-3.x, binaryfiles

I can read the first byte of a binary file like this:

```
with open(my_binary_file,'rb') as f:
    f.read(1)
```

But how do I do this with the module fileinput? If I run this code:

```
import fileinput
with fileinput.FileInput(my_binary_file,'rb') as f:
    f.read(1)
```

then I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'FileInput' object has no attribute 'read'
```

Is there a module similar to fileinput, which allows me to read bytes/characters of multiple binary files instead of lines?

EDIT: Reading a line of the binary file and looping over it is not an option, as the binary file is large and contains no line breaks.

Comment: what features of fileinput do you think you need, so that you can't just use open()?

Comment: I'm reading multiple binary files, which fileinput handles neatly. I'm also handling different file types. I think I'll just parse the input files from the command line and loop over them and use open instead of fileinput inside a generator function. I should probably delete this question.

Comment: `FileInput.readline` could possibly be redesigned to support a proper `limit` parameter. You could make an enhancement request.

Comment: @eryksun I was thinking of making an enhancement request, but I wouldn't know where to address it. It's probably not appropriate to submit a PEP? http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/#submitting-a-pep

Comment: You can submit an enhancement request here: [http://bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org). It may even get addressed if you include a working patch, but the core devs are a busy lot.

Comment: @eryksun Thanks for your suggestion. I posted to http://bugs.python.org/issue20992

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the solution I was after, but this is the solution I ended up with:

```
def process_binary_files(list_of_binary_files):

    for file in list_of_binary_files:
        with open(file,'rb') as f:
            yield f.read(1)

    return

list_of_binary_files = ['f1', 'f2']
generate_byte = process_binary_files(list_of_binary_files)
byte = next(generate_byte)
```